# Nested transaction for atomicity (Propogation.REQUIRED_NEW / Propogation.NESTED)

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactions, jpa-2.0, spring-transactions

First off, I'll note that I'm using Spring + Hibernate as my JPA2 implmentation.  My application is configured with a JpaTransactionManager and a HibernateJpaDialect.

I have a function to deactivate a unit, and I have a function that wraps deactivating multiple units.  The unit deactivation work makes a call to an external service, and if that call times out, or returns with an error status, it will throw an exception.  If a single unit deactivation fails (either through this external service call, or because of a RuntimeException), I want to rollback the transaction for *that* unit only.

I'm able to achieve this using Propogation.REQUIRES_NEW essentially as below:

```
@Transactional
public void deactivateUnits(List<String> names){
    for(String name : names){
        deactivateUnit(name);
    }
}
@Transactional(propogation=Propogation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor=MyException.class)
public void deactivateUnit(String name) throws MyException{
    ..snip..
    //Some code that throws MyExceptions or RuntimeExceptions
    ..snip..
}
```

And this works perfectly well.

This style extends very well to activation as well.

```
@Transactional
public void activateUnits(List<String> names){
    for(String name : names){
        activateUnit(name);
    }
}
@Transactional(propogation=Propogation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor=MyException.class)
public void activateUnit(String name) throws MyException{
    ..snip..
    //Some code that throws MyExceptions or RuntimeExceptions
    ..snip..
}
```

I run into a problem when it comes time to do `reactivation` however.  What I'd like is an atomic `reactivation` task that utilizes the existing `deactivateUnit` and `activateUnit` functions, such that if either the `deactivateUnit` or the `activateUnit` cause a rollback, the entire function will rollback.

My naiive attempt at this doesn't work:

```
@Transactional(propogation=Propogation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor=MyException.class)
public void reactivateUnit(String newName, String oldName) throws MyException{
    deactivateUnit(oldName);
    activateUnit(newName);
}
```

If `activateUnit` rolls back, `deactivateUnit` does not.

I thought that maybe I should change the propogation for activate and deactivate to `NESTED`, but that doesn't preserve the rollback behaviour of the functions.

I'm at a bit of a loss, so I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to make use of your originally annotated deactivateUnit function in this case.  You may have to try using a wrapper function with REQUIRES_NEW calling a helper function which is unannotated.  Then you would also call the helper function in your reactivateUnit method.